# Codemirror and Javascript: how to capture Control Keys

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have codemirror declared as follows:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
                    mode: "text/javascript",
                    extraKeys: {
                        "Ctrl-R": function() { 
                            // do something
                         },
                         "Ctrl-S": function() { 
                            // do something
                         }
                      }
                });
```

The `extraKeys` below work fine, however when the focus in in the editor element. If it is not, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> refreshes the screen, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> attempts to save the page. Is there a way to control the behavior of these keys beyond the text editor, to run the same function whether the focus in on the editor element or not?

Comment: Of course your current setup won't work outside of the text editor; you only have the event handler attached to that part of the DOM. Can you `CodeMirror` the entire `document`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO attempting to take that privilege of reloading/saving is bad for the end user but here's a possible solution:

```
    function editorCtrlR() { ... }

    function editorCtrlS() { ... }

    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
      mode: "text/javascript",
      extraKeys: {
            "Ctrl-R": editorCtrlR,
            "Ctrl-S": editorCtrlS
      }
    });

    document.onkeypress = function (event) {
        // detect key pressed
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            if (key === ('R').charCodeAt(0) - 64) editorCtrlR();
            if (key === ('S').charCodeAt(0) - 64) editorCtrlS();
        }
    }
```